# How to make section heading case sensitive in this?

Tags: section-titles

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno, two side]{amsart}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{ifpdf}
    \usepackage{array}
    
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
    \usepackage{cleveref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
    \usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
    \usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
    
    \usepackage{epstopdf} 
    \def\numset#1{{\\mathbb #1}}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{Lemma}[Th]{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{Cor}[Th]{Corollary}
    \newtheorem{Prop}[Th]{Proposition}
    
    \theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{Def}[Th]{Definition}
    \newtheorem{Conj}[Th]{Conjecture}
    \newtheorem{Rem}[Th]{Remark}
    \newtheorem{?}[Th]{Problem}
    \newtheorem{Ex}[Th]{Example}
    
    \newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
    \newcommand{\Hom}{{\rm{Hom}}}
    \newcommand{\diam}{{\rm{diam}}}
    \newcommand{\ovl}{\overline}
   
    
    \newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
      \begingroup
      \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
      \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
      \endgroup
    }
    
    \begin{document}

\title{BLABLA}

\author{Bhasth}
\author{Da}


\address{Uni\\ Department of Mathematics \\ 11}
\email{a.com}
\address{Sri  \\ i \\ 1107}
\email{ds.com}



\begin{abstract} The 
\end{abstract}

\keywords{to}



\subjclass[2010]{Pri0.}

\maketitle

\section{Make this case sensitive} 
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

EDIT- I want section heading appear as "Make this case sensitive" and not as "MAKE THIS CASE SENSITIVE"

Comment: Please make a *minimal* working example, that clearly shows your problem. I have currently no idea what exactly you are asking for. If you are talking about the formatting of the section title, that's just the way this class does it, and you probably shouldn't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `\begin{document}`, add the following lines:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
   \@startsection{section}{1}\z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}%
   {.5\linespacing}{\normalfont\centering}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno, two side]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
   \@startsection{section}{1}\z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}%
   {.5\linespacing}{\normalfont\centering}}
\makeatother
    
\begin{document}

\title{BLABLA}

\author{Bhasth}
\author{Da}

\address{Uni\\ Department of Mathematics \\ 11}
\email{a.com}
\address{Sri  \\ i \\ 1107}
\email{ds.com}

\begin{abstract} The 
\end{abstract}

\keywords{to}

\subjclass[2010]{Pri0.}

\maketitle

\section{Make this case sensitive} 
\lipsum

\end{document}
```